# Failed to upgrade AGP version

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I cannot update my project. When I try to do this I got this message

> The Upgrade Assistant failed to upgrade this project, finding no way of performing the Upgrade AGP version from 4.1.3 to 4.2.0 command, possibly because the project's build files use features not currently supported by the Upgrade Assistant (for example: using constants defined in buildSrc, or other unrecognized constructs, in Gradle build files).

What can i do about it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to manually change the gradle versions in `build.gradle.kts` (project) and then in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to version that matches your build.gradle.kts version

For example

build.gradle.kts
`"com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha14"`

gradle-wrapper.properties
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip`

Naturally, change the versions accordingly to what you're using

Comment: what is path of `build.gradle.kts`? kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had this happen because the Gradle plugin dependency declaration was in a separate variable. After moving the declaration back, directly to build.gradle as:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:$your_version'
    ...
    }
}
```

The error disappeared and Upgrade Assistant started working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the `Android Plugin Version` to fix this issue.  I was using `Version 3.0.2` and I moved to `Version 7.0.0`. I am happy to tell you this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have change the Gradle JDK version 1.8 -> 11 It fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I upgraded Android Studio to Canary without uninstalling my previous version.  Many issues were resolved when I pointed all IDEs to the same location of JDK.