# Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

i have a problem when try to run my app,
the build is success but the app open a moment, and then close.
I see this.
[image: Image log]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ProjetShop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I reviewed solutions how these
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33687
[Failed to upgrade AGP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497019/failed-to-upgrade-agp-version)
but , doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

it maybe download kotlin-compiler-embeddable jar!

this jar download is very very slow!

you need to check Android studio.

need Android studio build this React-native android project!